# the equivalent of python socket.send() in kdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, kdb

We are using symphony in our company and I am trying to send a message to the alert bot in symphony.

Someone sent me a small python script which does this already which uses the socket library.

They send the message as `socket.send(msg)` using `import socket` in their script.

Question is : what is socket.send comparable with in kdb ? It's not a http post so it's not the .Q.hp .. Is this similar -> `` {h:hopen hsym`$"host:port";h"someMessageCompatibleWithSymbphonyBot";hclose h} ``

UPDATE: I have been told that my kdb message is not `pure tcp`. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5):

`hopen` works for kdb-to-kdb, not kdb-to-other so yes in that sense it's not pure tcp.

Normally when kdb needs to communicate with another system by tcp you would use some sort of middleman library to handle the communication layer.

In theory you could use the python script/package in your kdb instance if you use one of the numerous kdb<>python interfaces (pyq, embedpy, qpython etc)

Comment: my idea as well but our system is a bit strict when it comes at bringing other technologies in.